# withForm causing 'Too Many Redirect' error on Grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails

I can not get withForm to work, and it has me stumped.  I am using grails 2.2.4 (we won't be upgrading to a higher version for several months,  but I'd like to add useToken="true" to my forms.

Here is my simple working method:

```
def browse () {

        def model =[:]
        model += [ attr1: "attr1", attr2: "attr2"]

}
```

In the gsp,  I simply print out the values of the attributes:

```
<g:form name='filterForm' action="browse" id='filterForm' method="post" 
    useToken="true">
    browse.gsp values:          
    ${attr1.toString()}
    ${attr2.toString()}
</g:form>
```

The above gsp prints out:
browse.gsp values:  attr1 attr2

Now, when I add a withForm into the controller method:

```
def browse () {
    withForm {
        def model =[:]
        model += [ attr1: "attr1", attr2: "attr2"]
    }.invalidToken{ response.status = 405}
}
```

I get a 'too many redirects' error.
The page does not require authentication,  the only mapping it would fall under is the generic

```
 "/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
```

The controller has no before or after interceptor set up.

This is happening on my local system where I am using GGTS as the IDE.

I have the same problem on Chromium and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Actually,  this is not the problem.  Apparently in creating a trimmed down example, I caused another issue.  I then thought the redirects were the root cause, but after more debugging I see that it is not related.

My original problem was that withForm was not returning any data from the model to the gsp, which was causing the gsp generation to fail.  I am not sure what is causing my stripped down version to get too many redirects, but it doesn't really matter at this point.

So, I've opened a new question with my real problem, and am just answering this one so that folks don't spend a lot of time on this issue.